# Association not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This error has been troubling me for weeks. When I try to build an `Item` from a specified `User` and `List`, the `Item` is created, but the association, `Wish` is not.

If i try to do `@item.lists.first.name` it returns an error:

```
undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm very new to rails, so I'm sure there is something that I have missed or misunderstood. Any help is thus much appreciated!

I have four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wishes, through: :lists
  has_many :items, through: :wishes

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wishes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :wishes

class Wish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :item

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes
  has_many :lists, through: :wishes
```

I want to create a new `Item` from `lists_controller.rb` show action:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @list = @user.lists.find(params[:id])
    @item = @list.items.build if current_user?(@user)
    @items = @list.items
  end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:list_id])
        @item = @list.items.build(params[:item])
    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "Item created!"
      redirect_to @item
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

My route file looks like this:

```
Wishlist::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :lists, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
  end
  resources :items, only: [:show, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

The form `lists/show.html.erb`:

```
   <div class="modal-body">
     <%= form_for(@item, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
        <%= render 'items/fields', f: f %>
         <%= hidden_field_tag :list_id, @list.id %>
  </div>
   </div>
```

and `items/fields`:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= f.label :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>

<%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %>
<%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :link %>
<%= f.text_field :link %>
```

**Update**

From the log:

```
Processing by ItemsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pcDVdaDzZz4M17Kwjx8mKw6tTF9MjUvx1woTzaKRWJY=", "item"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fecdd1fd890 @original_filename="profile.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[image]\"; filename=\"profile.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/6y/j8zfcgmd02x5s439c0np8fjh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130216-8413-3vzjuj>>, "remote_image_url"=>"", "title"=>"YES", "link"=>"SDFs"}, "list_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Add"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '5AXS8-7-YRyLyGDKYHIZRg' LIMIT 1
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."user_id" = 1 AND "lists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "items" ("created_at", "image", "link", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 16 Feb 2013 20:57:10 UTC +00:00], ["image", "profile.jpg"], ["link", "SDFs"], ["title", "YES"], ["updated_at", Sat, 16 Feb 2013 20:57:10 UTC +00:00]]
   (2.7ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/items/1
Completed 302 Found in 830ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

Comment: An `Item` has many lists, so you would need to call `item.lists.first.name`. That should fix the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: If I do that, it returns: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`. And if I call `item.wishes.first` it returns `nil`

Comment: I think [this Railscast on Nested Models](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) will help you with this domain.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've been watching the screencast, however as I'm very new to rails I'm unsure how to apply it to my case?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of googling, and trial and error, I found that I had to build the Wish explicitly. The create action ended up looking like this:

```
def create
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = Item.create!(params[:item])
    @item.wishes.build(list_id: @list.id)
    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "Item created!"
      redirect_to @item
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to summarize first: you have users, which have lists, which contain wishes, which are related to one particular item.

So let's have a look at the following line of code first:

```
@item.lists.first.name
```

So what happens is, that rails takes the item, goes through the wishes to all lists that contain this item, takes the first list and looks for the lists name. The problem you see occurs when the item is not related to any lists through wishes (e.g. because your create method for items does not connect new items to wishes and therefore the connection to the list is missing as well): So the item has no relation to a list and the result for `@item.lists` is an empty list. And well, the `first` element of an empty list is nothing (`nil`) and of course `nil` has no name.

The result is, what you see:

```
undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass
```

One way to fix this, is to use `try()` which executes the related method only if it is available:

```
@item.lists.first.try(:name)
```

The other problem, you were talking about, is that no wish is generated, when you build an item from a user. I think you have to explicitly build the wish. I'm not 100% sure, but I think, declaring `:through`-relations in the model is only used for queries, not for generating/building.

Try something like the following in your items controller (The idea is to build the wish explicitly first, and after that build the item for the wish):

```
@wish = @list.wishes.build()
@wish.save
@item = @wish.item.build(params[:item])
```

Comment: I tried the `@item = @list.wishes.build().items.build(params[:item])`, however now it returns `undefined method 'items' for #<Wish:0x007f8b45bf1af8>`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. A wish belongs_to one item, so it must be singular: `@item = @list.wishes.build().item.build(params[:item])`

Comment: I also realised, that `build` only instantiates an element, but does not save it. I edited the post accordingly. Please look at the last two lines.

Comment: And one more comment, this time about the database design. Do you store any additional information with a wish? If not, it would be more appropriate to use a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between lists and items, where a list has_and_belongs_to_many items and the other way round. The table in between would not be called wishes, but items_lists.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, however, now it returns `undefined method 'item' for true:TrueClass`. And I thought the point of a HMT-relationship was that the entry in the join table was created automatically? Eventually I will store information in a wish, which is why I went with HMT.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue (but not really an issue) when using `build` on a `has_many :through`. You need to change the association for `items` on `List` to include `inverse_of`.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wishes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :wishes, inverse_of: :wishes
end
```

It should then build the connecting `Wish` object for you properly.

See this relevant issue for more information: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7661#issuecomment-8614206

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, this did not work for me. I read through your reference with no luck either. Still the exact same issue